# Jump to next occurence of different characters

Tags: vim

I had some latex tables, that needed some header formating:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Foo bar bla & blabar & sdf \\
\hline
[table content]
\end{tablular}
```

where all items in the first row should get a `\textbf{}` tag.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Foo bar bla} & \textbf{blabar} & \textbf{sdf} \\
\hline
[table content]
\end{tablular}
```

my macro goes like this:

```
^
qq
i
\textbf{<ESC>
f&
h
i
}<ESC>
ww
q
2@q
```

on the last item i dont get the closing bracket, because there is no more `&`. how can i jump with vim to to next occurence of `&` or `\\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
f&
```

you could do a search:

```
/\v [&\\]
```

which will land you on the space before `&` *and* `\`, ready to do:

```
i}
```

`\v` means "very magic" and allows us to save some `\`.

Comment: this requires the user to know how many times (the count of `& or \\`) he/she should replay the macro. otherwise it could affect other lines.

Comment: @kent, you are right in principle, but the OP uses a macro to wrap a single "item" and executes it `n` times. Your answer is more generic (and thus, probably better) but my answer is a bit more topical, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `:s` instead of macro:

```
s/\(.*\)\\\\/\='\\textbf{' . substitute(submatch(1),'&','} & \\textbf{','g') . "}\\\\"/
```